# How do I make arrow color White in Toolbar

Tags: android

I'm new developer. And I just add **back arrow** in **Toolbar** but it's Black color. How do i make it white. Here is my code below :

**Java**

```
setSupportActionBar(newToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

**XML FILE**

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/newToolBarId"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by editing styles.xml:

```
<style name="ToolbarColoredBackArrow" parent="AppTheme">
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">#ffffff</item>
```

...then referencing the style in the Toolbar definition in the activity:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/main_parent_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
```